# Filtering JSON list in shell using jq

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, filter, jq

**Input :**

```
{ "names" : ["name1","name2","name3","pat_name4"] }
```

**Needed output :**

```
{ "names" : ["name1","name2","name3"] }
```

Currently what i have by running command, to filter out all names starting with `pat_`

```
cat file | jq .names | grep -Ev '^(pat_)'
```

is this

```
["name1","name2","name3"]
```

Was wondering if there is some alteration to the **jq** command that could be done to get in the format needed.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Your data is already in JSON format. The only change you seem to be making is removing one of the strings from the array. You're not changing the format at all.

Comment: @Barmar - The OP wants the output as the object, not the array. That's the "format" issue.  However, the question is not clear as to whether or not ALL items matching the regex should be excluded. Sandeep - please clarify.

Comment: BTW, `cat file | jq` would be more efficiently written as `<file jq`, `jq <file`, or `jq ... file`. The performance difference isn't huge for `jq` specifically, but it's a good habit to be in because for other programs it can be much larger --  with `wc -c`, for example, it's O(1) with a real file handle (can `seek()` and `tell()` in constant time), but O(n) with a pipe. Similarly, `sort` can parallelize with a seekable handle, but has to read from the front with a pipe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In examples like this, `cat file | something` is often a placeholder for `some command that produces output | something`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Appreciate the input. This was just an example as Barmer pointed out

Comment: @peak yes, I was hoping it to be self-explanatory perhaps I should have been more clear. I needed all the values matching regex to be excluded and thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's an... odd situation here, though, that you accepted an answer that doesn't actually answer the question as described in the title -- someone else who really *does* want to know how to go from a list of strings to a JSON document won't find this question very useful. Perhaps you might edit the title to something like *Filtering a JSON list in shell*, so people can figure out what the question's answers will actually help them do from the title?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. The title was based on my original intention of the question, but i wasn't aware of filtering out json list through jq directly. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your input, the invocation:

```
$ jq -c '.names |= map(select(test("^pat_")|not))'
```

produces:

```
{"names":["name1","name2","name3"]}
```